# Unable to find an entry point named 'Reset' in DLL 'CIMWin32.dll'

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport, win32com

`[DllImport("CIMWin32.dll")]
public static extern UInt32 Reset();`

When I Am Calling This Method Then I Getting Exception

> Unable to find an entry point named 'Reset' in DLL 'CIMWin32.dll'

Comment: Why do you think there is a `Reset` method in this dll?

Comment: @KrivitskiyGrigoriy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/reset-method-in-class-cim-controller I think it's in the docs.

Comment: You can only call methods that have public entry points.  DllImport looks at the symbol table of the dll and if the method is not an entry point than it is not in the symbol table and you can't call the method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `Reset` method of `CIM` you want to import and invoke, but this is how you can call a method in `VMI`. Install [System.Management](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/) package via NuGet. Then you need to create an instance of `ManagementClass` like below:

```
var NamespacePath = "\\\\.\\ROOT\\cimv2";
var ClassName = "CIM_LogicalDevice";

ManagementClass managementClass = new ManagementClass(NamespacePath + ":" + ClassName);           

managementClass .InvokeMethod("Reset", null);
```

Of course in the code above, `Reset` [method is not implemented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/cim-logicaldevice). You can find your provider, class, and method in [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/cim-wmi-provider). For e.g above, I tried to call the `Reset` method of `CIM_LogicalDevice` class.

In the requirement section, you can see the namespace.

[image].

If you look for the more complicated example of how to invoke WMI class methods, take a look on this example on Microsoft Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/configmgr/develop/core/clients/programming/how-to-call-a-wmi-class-method-by-using-system.management